# What's the name of this parameter?

Tags: solar-energy, photovoltaics

$ P_m=P_n*{G\frac1{G_{STC}}}*[1-\gamma*(T_c-25)]$

This equation is applied on sollar cells. $ P_m$ is the mean power produced in 15 minutes, $P_n$ is the nominal power [W], G is the insolation [W/m2], $G_{STC}$ (the subscript still in the wrong place, I don't know why) is the radiation [W/m2] in standard testing conditions [reference here](https://sinovoltaics.com/learning-center/quality/normal-operating-cell-temperature-noct-definition-noct-definition/). Last, but nost least, $T_c$ is the cell temperature.

What is the parameter gamma ($\gamma$)? I have a value for gamma, 0.005 [adimensional], but I don't know what it means or its definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [temperature coefficient](https://sinovoltaics.com/solar-basics/measuring-the-temperature-coefficients-of-a-pv-module/) of the panel. It varies by panel, but 0.005 (0.5%) is a fairly normal value for it. Its unit is 1/degree C. It's the rate at which cell efficiency drops off, as the cell temperature rises above 25 degrees C.